# how to use model1 reference in model2 so that changes in model1 reflects in model2 automatically

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have two model group model and user model

user model :

```
var mongoose    =   require('mongoose');
var userSchema  = mongoose.Schema({
     profilePic : String,
     firstName  : String,
     lastName   : String,
     dateOfBirth_DateObject     : { 
        type : Date ,   
        default : Date(1994-03-18)
     },
     yearOfBirth_Integer : { 
        type : Number,  
        default : 0 
     },
     monthOfBirth_Integer  : { 
        type : Number,  
        default : 0 
     },
     dayOfBirth_Integer : { 
        type : Number,  
        default : 0 
     },
     gender_String  : String
)};
module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema,'user');
```

group model :

```
var mongoose       =   require('mongoose');
var groupSchema    =   mongoose.Schema({
   members      :   [{
        id      :   {
           type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
           ref  : 'user'
        },
        firstName   :   String,
        lastName    :   String,
        profilePic :    String

    }]
});

module.exports     =    mongoose.model('group', groupSchema,'group');
```

so when user uploads new profile pic, url of that pic has been saved in user model but profile pic of that user should also automatically change in group members array.

Comment: It seems like you could do this much more simply by eliminating all the properties from the members array and just make it an array of users.  Then any query to the group schema, you populate the users array and you'll have all the data, first, last, and profile pic.  It seems like you are duplicating data where you don't need to.

Comment: something like: `var groupSchema = mongoose.Schema({ members: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'}]);`.  Then in your queries to the group schema such as `find()` do something like:  `Group.find().populate('members')` and you'll have an array of users including the names and profile pic

Comment: Actually there are other fields also but i want only first namem last name and profile pic to be populated to group model

Comment: in that case, you can pass a list of properties you do not want to populate:  `.populate("members", "-<field1> -<field2> -<etc...>")` and it will exclude those properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your schema into

```
var groupSchema = mongoose.Schema({members : [{
    id      :   {
       type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref  : 'user'
    },
    otherprop1:   String,
    otherprop2  :   String,

}]});
```

Then use populate to get user data in find

```
group.find({}).populate({path:"user", select: "firstName lastName profilePic"})
```